# merging two arrays of hashes wisely

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to combine two arrays of hashes arr1 and arr2:

```
arr1 = [{"id"=>1, "a"=>1, "c"=>2}, {"id"=>2, "a"=>1}]
arr2 = [{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "b"=>20}, {"id"=>3, "b"=>2}]
```

And I want the result to include all elements in both arrays, but the ones that have the same value for the "id" key, should be merged so that if a key exists in both hashes, it should be selected from arr2, otherwise, it just picks the value from any hash that the key exists in. So the combination of the example above would be:

```
combined = [
            {"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "b"=>20, "c"=>2}, # "id"=>1 exists in both, so they are merged
            {"id"=>2, "a"=>1}, 
            {"id"=>3, "b"=>2}
           ]
```

The code below works, but I am new to Ruby and I am sure there is a better way to do this. Can you provide a more ruby-ic way?

```
         combined = []
         # merge items that exist in both and add to combined
         arr1.each do |a1|
            temp = arr2.select {|a2| a2["id"] == a1["id"]}[0]
            
            if temp.present?
              combined << temp.reverse_merge(a1)
            end
          end

          # Add items that exist in arr1 but not in arr2
          arr1.each do |a1|
            if arr2.pluck("id").exclude? a1["id"]
              combined << a1
            end
          end

          # Add items that exist in arr2 but not in arr1
          arr2.each do |a2|
            if arr1.pluck("id").exclude? a2["id"]
              combined << a2
            end
          end
```

Comment: checkout my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that no two elements (hashes) of `arr1`, `g` and `h`, have the property that `g["id"] == h["id"]`.

In this case one could write:

```
(arr1 + arr2).each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }) { |g,h|
  h[g["id"]].update(g) }.values
  #=> [{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "c"=>2, "b"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "a"=>1},
  #    {"id"=>3, "b"=>2}]
```

Note that:

```
(arr1 + arr2).each_with_object(Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }) { |g,h|
  h[g["id"]].update(g) }
  #=> {1=>{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "c"=>2, "b"=>20}, 2=>{"id"=>2, "a"=>1},
  #    3=>{"id"=>3, "b"=>2}}
```

If a hash is defined:

```
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {} }
```

then, possibly after keys have been added to `h`, if `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k] = {}` is executed and the empty hash is returned. See the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that takes a block. See also [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `Hash#merge!`).

One may alternatively write:

```
(arr1 + arr2).each_with_object({}) { |g,h| (h[g["id"]] ||= {}).update(g) }.values
  #=> {1=>{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "c"=>2, "b"=>20}, 2=>{"id"=>2, "a"=>1},
  #    3=>{"id"=>3, "b"=>2}}
```

Another way is to use [Emumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), where the grouping is on the value of the key `"id"`:

```
(arr1 + arr2).group_by { |h| h["id"] }.values.map { |a| a.reduce(&:merge) }
#=> [{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "c"=>2, "b"=>20}, {"id"=>2, "a"=>1}, {"id"=>3, "b"=>2}]
```

Comment: Thanks @Cary, your first and second solutions have one issue. The first item in the combined result lacks the key-value that only exists in arr1.  The first item should be `{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "b"=>20, "c"=>2}` but your solution returns `{"id"=>1, "a"=>10, "b"=>20}` 
But the last solution works fine. I believe it's because it uses merge. Can you update your initial solution?

Comment: Thank you for catching my errors. I've fixed them.